# Procedure/Function to find and fill empty time spots

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a table named `DAILY_EVENTS` and it holds data like this:

```
EVENT_ID   | EVENT_TYPE       | From_date           | To_date
-----------+------------+-----+---------------------+---------------------
3          | ACCIDENT         | 2013-01-05 01:14:47 | 2013-01-05 01:14:55
6          | TERRORISM        | 2013-01-05 22:55:20 | 2013-01-05 22:56:00
8          | NATURAL DISASTER | 2013-01-05 16:05:30 | 2013-01-05 16:05:39
```

I need to find empty time spots to insert more rows for this day with these conditions:

**a)** Time ranges cannot be superimposed. i.e. new rows **From_date** and **To_date** cannot be in the range between `01:14:47` to `01:14:55`, or `22:55:20` to `22:56:00` and so on.

**b)** 10 seconds between **From_date** time and **To_date** time i.e `01:14:00` - `01:14:10`

**c)** minimum of 2 seconds between the **To_date** of the event previously inserted and the  **from_date** of the current event i.e. if First row is `01:14:00` - `01:14:10`, then second row must starts minimum at `01:14:12`, and the **To_Date** will be `01:14:22`

A summary of 2 new rows (last ones) with allowed data could be these:

```
EVENT_ID   | EVENT_TYPE       | From_date           | To_date
-----------+------------+-----+---------------------+---------------------
3          | ACCIDENT         | 2013-01-05 01:14:47 | 2013-01-05 01:14:55
6          | TERRORISM        | 2013-01-05 22:55:20 | 2013-01-05 22:56:00
8          | NATURAL DISASTER | 2013-01-05 16:05:30 | 2013-01-05 16:05:39
3          | ACCIDENT         | 2013-01-05 00:00:00 | 2013-01-05 00:00:10
6          | ACCIDENT         | 2013-01-05 00:00:12 | 2013-01-05 00:00:22
```

I'm kinda blocked with this requirement, I don't know how can I start with, any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate all the gaps using:

```sql
SELECT LAG(to_date, 1, TRUNC(from_date)) OVER (ORDER BY From_date) AS gap_start,
       from_date AS gap_end
FROM   daily_events
WHERE  to_date   > DATE '2013-01-05'
AND    from_date < DATE '2013-01-05' + INTERVAL '1' DAY
UNION ALL
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(to_date), DATE '2013-01-05'),
       DATE '2013-01-05' + INTERVAL '1' DAY
FROM   daily_events
WHERE  to_date   > DATE '2013-01-05'
AND    from_date < DATE '2013-01-05' + INTERVAL '1' DAY;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE daily_events (EVENT_ID, EVENT_TYPE, From_date, To_date) AS
SELECT 3, 'ACCIDENT',         DATE '2013-01-05' + INTERVAL '01:14:47' HOUR TO SECOND, DATE '2013-01-05' + INTERVAL '01:14:55' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 'TERRORISM',        DATE '2013-01-05' + INTERVAL '22:55:20' HOUR TO SECOND, DATE '2013-01-05' + INTERVAL '22:56:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 8, 'NATURAL DISASTER', DATE '2013-01-05' + INTERVAL '16:05:30' HOUR TO SECOND, DATE '2013-01-05' + INTERVAL '16:05:39' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | GAP_START | GAP_END |
> | --- | --- |
> | 2013-01-05 00:00:00 | 2013-01-05 01:14:47 |
> | 2013-01-05 01:14:55 | 2013-01-05 16:05:30 |
> | 2013-01-05 16:05:39 | 2013-01-05 22:55:20 |
> | 2013-01-05 22:56:00 | 2013-01-06 00:00:00 |

Then you just need to pick a 10-second range within those gaps.

---

You can generate all the possible non-overlapping 10-second intervals, starting from 2-seconds after the end of the previous interval, using a recursive query:

```sql
WITH gaps (gap_start, gap_end) AS (
  SELECT LAG(to_date, 1, TRUNC(from_date)) OVER (ORDER BY From_date),
         from_date
  FROM   daily_events
  WHERE  to_date   > DATE '2013-01-05'
  AND    from_date < DATE '2013-01-05' + INTERVAL '1' DAY
UNION ALL
  SELECT COALESCE(MAX(to_date), DATE '2013-01-05'),
         DATE '2013-01-05' + INTERVAL '1' DAY
  FROM   daily_events
  WHERE  to_date   > DATE '2013-01-05'
  AND    from_date < DATE '2013-01-05' + INTERVAL '1' DAY
),
intervals (gap_start, gap_end, int_start, int_end) AS (
  SELECT gap_start,
         gap_end,
         gap_start + INTERVAL '2' SECOND,
         gap_start + INTERVAL '12' SECOND
  FROM   gaps
  WHERE  gap_start + INTERVAL '14' SECOND <= gap_end
UNION ALL
  SELECT gap_start,
         gap_end,
         int_end + INTERVAL '2' SECOND,
         int_end + INTERVAL '12' SECOND
  FROM   intervals
  WHERE  int_end + INTERVAL '14' SECOND <= gap_end
)
SEARCH DEPTH FIRST BY gap_start SET int_order
SELECT int_start, int_end
FROM   intervals;
```

Which, for the sample data, outputs:

> | INT_START | INT_END |
> | --- | --- |
> | 2013-01-05 00:00:02 | 2013-01-05 00:00:12 |
> | 2013-01-05 00:00:14 | 2013-01-05 00:00:24 |
> | 2013-01-05 00:00:26 | 2013-01-05 00:00:36 |
> | ... | ... |
> | 2013-01-05 01:14:02 | 2013-01-05 01:14:12 |
> | 2013-01-05 01:14:14 | 2013-01-05 01:14:24 |
> | 2013-01-05 01:14:26 | 2013-01-05 01:14:36 |
> | 2013-01-05 01:14:57 | 2013-01-05 01:15:07 |
> | 2013-01-05 01:15:09 | 2013-01-05 01:15:19 |
> | 2013-01-05 01:15:21 | 2013-01-05 01:15:31 |
> | ... | ... |
> | 2013-01-05 16:04:45 | 2013-01-05 16:04:55 |
> | 2013-01-05 16:04:57 | 2013-01-05 16:05:07 |
> | 2013-01-05 16:05:09 | 2013-01-05 16:05:19 |
> | 2013-01-05 16:05:41 | 2013-01-05 16:05:51 |
> | 2013-01-05 16:05:53 | 2013-01-05 16:06:03 |
> | 2013-01-05 16:06:05 | 2013-01-05 16:06:15 |
> | ... | ... |
> | 2013-01-05 22:56:26 | 2013-01-05 22:56:36 |
> | 2013-01-05 22:56:38 | 2013-01-05 22:56:48 |
> | 2013-01-05 22:56:50 | 2013-01-05 22:57:00 |
> | 2013-01-05 22:57:02 | 2013-01-05 22:57:12 |
> | 2013-01-05 22:57:14 | 2013-01-05 22:57:24 |
> | 2013-01-05 22:57:26 | 2013-01-05 22:57:36 |
> | ... | ... |
> | 2013-01-05 23:59:14 | 2013-01-05 23:59:24 |
> | 2013-01-05 23:59:26 | 2013-01-05 23:59:36 |
> | 2013-01-05 23:59:38 | 2013-01-05 23:59:48 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/markdown?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5ed8a6b17d963d459d459949ed996387)*

Comment: Thank you sir! I'm going to test it, didnt know about the LAG ans COALESCE functions, I'm going to search about them to understand your code better